# Can a husband forbid his wife from doing something (which will not hurt her)

Tags: halacha, marriage, nedarim-shevuot

A husband cannot make his wife do something using a vow ([Helckas Mehokek 74.17](https://www.sefaria.org/Chelkat_Mechokek.74.17?lang=bi) end, [Bais Shmuel 74.12 end](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Shmuel.74.12?lang=bi)).

> אם מדיר אותה דבר שהוא לטובתה כגון שהדיר קונם הנאת תשמישך עלי אם לא תתקשט והיא אינה רוצה א"י לכופה והנדר חל והוא אין לו דין מורד והיא אינה מורדת ולאחר ששה חדשים יוצי' ויתן הכתובה כמ"ש [בסי' ע"ז:](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.76.11?lang=bi)

The Shach writes ([235.16](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6678)) that if she was the one who made a vow, he can force her to do things by annulling the vow on condition that she does them, as long as they are not degrading.

---

But **theoretically** can a husband forbid his wife from doing something (that does not hurt her)?

For example if he tells her "relations with you are forbidden to me if you go to your parents house during this next week" ([halachikly](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.74.4) it only hurts her to not go to her parents for more than a month - if they live in the same city).

Is she allowed to go to her parents house (during this week)?
What happens if she does?
Does it make her a moredes?

PS. How about not theoretically?

Sources please

Comment: I remember that the gemara does deal with this but will have to find it.

Comment: @sabbahillel i guess to start here https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.70a.7

Comment: As I recall, it is a discussion if *a person says his wife is forbidden if she visits her father before succos* and the discussion concerns exactly what is involved and when it takes effect. It might also be in the Rambam.

Comment: @sabbahillel rambam halacha 12 here http://www.chabad.org/952887/ (ishut 13)

Comment: I think that it would be in masechet nedarim as well involving a conditional neder. If he makes a neder if she goes to her father before succos, what is done until succos.

Comment: @sabbahillel i do not see in nedarim

Comment: What mechanism do you think will force her to do what he wants?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons if she makes a vow forbidding relations with her husband on herself, then her husband annuls it on condition she should take out the garbage, if she does not take out the garbage he can divorce her and she does not receive her Kesuba, (because he can not have relations with her because of her)

Comment: In my understanding, the Parashat Nedarim is not related to marriage at all, meaning it takes precedence over marital obligations just because it is a more serious offense, like one that forbids Matzah for himself is forbidden to eat the Mizvah Matzah on Seder. Moreover, the relations between the couple are either financial or sexual, I couldn't find anything in-between. That's why the only way of "influencing" the woman, including forbidding thing on her,  is through her obligation to respect her husband, just like Kibud Av veEm.

Answer (score 3):

I am merely translating the passage quoted by the questioner from the Chelkas Mechokek Shulchan Aruch even hoezer 74,17 which gives us the answers:

> אם מדיר אותה דבר שהוא לטובתה כגון שהדיר קונם הנאת תשמישך עלי אם לא תתקשט והיא אינה רוצה א"י לכופה והנדר חל והוא אין לו דין מורד והיא אינה מורדת ולאחר ששה חדשים יוצי' ויתן הכתובה כמ"ש בסי' ע"ז:
>
> If the Husband makes a stipulation that leads to a neder forbidding himself from relations with his wife, even if that stipulation is for her own benefit e.g., "if you don't apply make up (which women generally want to do), then your relations are forbidden to me" - he cannot force her to comply, so if she doesn't apply make up the neder is triggered i.e she is now forbidden for relations to him. He is not a Mored (which would incur a forced divorce straight away and payment of kesuba if husband is mored by making a Neder she cannot live with) and She is not a moredes (which would incur a forced divorce straight away without the payment of the kesuba). So we wait 6 months which is the maximum wait for relations for a woman (e.g if her husband is a sailor) and he should then divorce her with a Kesuba unless she wants to remain married despite being forbidden to her husband as prescribed in Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 77.

So we see that if she transgresses her husband's stipulation even against her own benefit (e.g., not put make up on), that triggers her husbands neder to forbid her relations. This is in spite of the husband making a positve stipulation that he may think is for her own good.
Stipulating to not let her see her parents for a week while it might not affect her for just 1 week (which is why the husband is not a Mored), is a negative stipulation that encroaches on her freedom. If she can transgress a positive stipulation, how much more so should she be allowed to transgress a negative stipulation to go and see them if she wants to, thus forbiding relations with her husband, remaining married for the next 6 months leading to divorce with kesuba and she is not a Moredes.

Conclusion: A husband that Dominates his wife's normal freedom that the Torah allows, by making stipulations leading to nedarim to disallow her to do something, cannot force the wife to comply.
If she does not keep the stipulation even though the Husband's neder now works that she can no longer have relations with him  (if she has relations she transgresses lo yachel devaro), her choice  to not keep the tenai (stipulation), enables her to receive a forced divorce after 6 months no relations, and she gets her full kesuba.

Comment: +1 thanks for you work, can you please prove or provide evidence that your statement **"If she can transgress a positive stipulation, how much more so should she be allowed to transgress a negative stipulation to go and see them if she wants to"** is true, to me it seems possible that the reason she is not a Moredes is because she was passive and did not actively do something, but if she actively "transgress a negative stipulation" she might be a moredes, please prove my logic wrong

Comment: Is my understanding of the shach quoted in the OP wrong?

Comment: Passivity can be penalized as well as active transgression with regards to moredes.We see that if she refuses relations to her husband for 4 weeks he can divorce her without a Kesuba even though she is not doing anything see kesubos 63b and SA EH 77,2. So the fundemental point of the Chelkas Mechokek is that even "לטובתה"- for her benefit she can transgress his tenai, because of limiting her freedom, and how much more so when he limits her freedom for no reason.

Comment: As with regards to the shach you are right that since it is **she** making the vow, it is not unreasonable for him to annul her vow on condition she does something that is not demeaning because without his Haphara she would be much worst off stuck with her Neder. But if  **he** makes a neder with a stipulation against her he can't force her to comply at all.

Comment: it is possible that the stipulation was for her to not do something **for her own good** (the vow will take affect if she does something bad for her)

Comment: it seems sometimes she is not **worse off**, it is considered his fault see https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.74.2?lang=he and https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Shmuel.74.5

Comment: Refusing relations is not passive , a woman in relations is passive, if she is refusing she is active, I do not yet see a clear proof that I am wrong or that you are right

Comment: In the vast majority of cases it is passive to refuse relations, as the husband is not allowed to rape his wife Nedarim 20b, everyone knows this from chosson lessons

Comment: in practice you are right but theoreticaly maybe not see bottom paragraph on the right here http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1096&pgnum=241

Comment: Trust me i have learnt kesubos beiyun and rav Naftoli Tzvi berlin is refering to measures to coerce her to go back with her husband by the the likes of monetary penanlties incurred that will make her go back to her husband begrudgedly but willingly, but never through rape like shechem. The same can be said when we force the husband to give a Get, it is through monetary penalties see kesubos 63a-b

Comment: I thought he is talking about bedieved

Comment: so if someone coerces a girl in the street using other things it is considered rape? Will he need to pay the fines?

Comment: I still do not see you prove or provide evidence that your statement **"If she can transgress a positive stipulation, how much more so should she be allowed to transgress a negative stipulation to go and see them if she wants to"** is true, and mine is wrong, except your claim that I should trust you

Comment: what i meant by trust is that you have not looked up the source i told you in kesubos 63a-b and meforshim, so trust me because i have looked it up. when you pick up an artscroll you will be able to verify what i said is true

Comment: please be more specific what should I look at (even if her rebelling is active I still do not see it as evidence that you are right)

Comment: Should we delete all comments (except my first one) and you answer it,

Comment: kesubos 63a a moredes loses 7 dinars a week this means that she refuses to have relations, some say it also means she refuses to do the work cut out for her. 64b we pasken like rabboseinu that after 4 weeks she loses her entire kesuba if she is warned, We are only Kofe her when she says she is refusing in spite but if she is disgusted by him it is a machlokes if we are kofe her. rashi explains kofe means to force her to remain married (not to force her to have relations). i don't want to be rude but i think you can give me a tick now but its your desision

Comment: I gave you a +1 but not a check mark yet because you did not prove your are right yet, (I will give you a few check marks to your other answers) you did not give me a lot of new information in your last comment, my problem with you answer is **If she can transgress a positive stipulation, how much more so should she be allowed to transgress a negative stipulation** since one is by sitting and not doing anything and the other is by doing something active

Comment: by sitting and refusing to have relations she is moredes. the gemora kesubos says that she is forced to remain married with a monetory punishment of 7 dinars a week and at the end with 4 weeks she loses the right to her entire kesuba. If the word koffe -"forced" meant that the husband can rape his wife then it is unfair to punish her monetarily which is why rashi 63b says that kofe means she is "forced to remain married"so when refusing relations she is passive as he can't rape her ned20b